# How to use variables from one function in another in python? Where the only difference in functions is the return statement

Tags: python, function, return

I have two functions which are exactly the same except for the return statements. 
How do I use the variables in one function to allow me to shorten the second function?

`heuristic` and `heuristic2` are the original functions and ideally I'd turn one of the two into something like `heuristic3`.

These aren't the complete functions, but just enough to get an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
def heuristic(self, state):
    for currentState in argsWith0:
        endX = (currentState - 1) // 3
        endY = (currentState - 1) % 3
        newSquare = state[currentState]
        currentDistanceToDirtyNode = abs(endX - startX) + abs(endY - startY)
        if currentDistanceToDirtyNode < distanceToSquare:
            distanceToSquare = currentDistanceToDirtyNode
    return 2 * (distanceToSquare * numDirtySquares + 1) + sum( \
        (numDirtySquares - x) * 4 + 1 for x in range(0, numDirtySquares + 1))


def heuristic2(self, state):
    for currentState in argsWith0:
        endX = (currentState - 1) // 3
        endY = (currentState - 1) % 3
        newSquare = state[currentState]
        currentDistanceToDirtyNode = abs(endX - startX) + abs(endY - startY)
        if currentDistanceToDirtyNode < distanceToSquare:
            distanceToSquare = currentDistanceToDirtyNode
    return 2 * (distanceToSquare * numDirtySquares + 1) + sum( \
        (numDirtySquares - x) * 4 + 1 for x in range(0, numDirtySquares + 1))


def heuristic3(self, state):
    return heuristic2(state) + 2 * \
           (heuristic2(state).distanceToSquare * heuristic2(state).numDirtySquares + 1)
```

Comment: seems like both functions are the same if only return is different then write a single function with different conditions.

Comment: Does this code run? `distanceToSquare` is never assigned before its used

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at something called 'global' variables: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables

Essentially, a variable defined outside a function, will allow all functions to be able to access and manipulate that variable, while variables defined inside a function are 'local' and can only be used within that specific function.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't directly access state of a variable within a function. If you would like to access variables like this

```
heuristic2(state).distanceToSquare
```

Then you'd have to make `heuristic2` return a class with the property `distanceToSquare`

```
class Heuristic():
    def __init__(self, val, dis, dirt):
        self.value = value
        self.distanceToSquare = dis
        self.numDirtySquares = dirt
```

And adjust the return statement to return each value as part of the class

```
v = 2 * (distanceToSquare * numDirtySquares + 1) + sum( \
        (numDirtySquares - x) * 4 + 1 for x in range(0, numDirtySquares + 1))
return Heuristic(v, distanceToSquare, numDirtySquares)
```

---

```
def heuristic3(self, state):
    h2 = heuristic2(state)
    return h2.value + 2 * (h2.distanceToSquare * h2.numDirtySquares + 1)
```